# can we use multiple "cd" commands in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I was not able to add multiple change directory commands in a single batch file:

```
cd C:\abc\def 
do something  
cd C:\def\ghi 
do something
```

It stops in the second line, and does not come back to execute the third line.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

I am betting that what you're doing in step 2 is calling another batch file, without using the `call` keyword.

Comment: I was not calling another batch file, I called the build file in the second line.

Comment: Calling it - how? What is the line?

Comment: gradle task clean build

Comment: Isn't "gradle" a batch file? (Sorry, I'm not familiar with gradle)

Comment: Its a gradle build. But the thing It is just executing that gradle build and should come back to the next step. But that is not happening